# how to build the scripted query using java API

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the following code to build the scripted query

```
ScriptQueryBuilder sb = new ScriptQueryBuilder( new Script("ctx._source.id=9"));

--> This is produing the following ES query where script tag has been created twice
    {
      "script" : {
        "script" : {
          "inline" : "ctx._source.id=9",
          "lang" : "painless"
        },
        "boost" : 1.0
      }
    }
```

When I changed to query builder still the script tag has been generating twice how to overcome

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.scriptQuery(new Script("ctx._source.id=9"));

{
  "script" : {
    "script" : {
      "inline" : "ctx._source.id=9",
      "lang" : "painless"
    },
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

M i missing anything ?How to remove the extra script tag?

Below is the code which m using

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.scriptQuery(new Script("ctx._source.id=10"));
Update update = new Update.Builder(qb).index(index).type(type).id("1").build();

            JestResult result = JestClientInstance.getInstance().getClient().execute(update);
```

Comment: There's no extra script tag, that's how it's supposed to be. See here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html

Comment: Hi Val, Thanks For your comment , but when running the above query m getting the following exception                                         {"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"[script] unknown field [type], parser not found"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"[script] unknown field [type], parser not found"}

Comment: Are you sure this is the query you're running? The error is complaining about `type` which is not present in your script.

Comment: What version of ES are you running by the way?

Comment: ES 5.2  This is the update query m using      Update update = new Update.Builder(qb).index(index).type(type).id("1").build();
  
  try {
   JestResult result = JestClientInstance.getInstance().getClient().execute(update);

Comment: Add your code to your question, it's more legible.

Comment: Val How to add the type in the script because when I run the below query from sense its working fine                                                      POST /jesttest/jesttest_type/1/_update
{
    "script" : {
      "inline" : "ctx._source.id=9",
      "lang" : "painless"
    },
    "boost" : 1.0
}

Comment: you don't add the type in the script, it's in the URL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142130/discussion-between-prasad-kp-and-val).